# prepareForSegue - CollectionView/TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, uicollectionview

How can I use *indexPathForSelectedRow* in CollectionView?

CollectionView/TableView:

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("levelCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    guard levelListen != nil else {
        return cell
    }

    let levelListe = levelListen[indexPath.row]
    cell.levelLabel?.text = levelListe.name

    return cell
}
```

TableView - prepareForSegue (work):

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "zumLevel" {
        let dstCtl = segue.destinationViewController as! InLevelViewController

        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        dstCtl.levelList = levelListen[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

CollectionView - prepareForSegue (not work):

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "zumLevel" {
        let dstCtl = segue.destinationViewController as! InLevelViewController

        // like TableView?
        let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
        dstCtl.levelList = levelListen[indexPath.row]  //  <--- .row doesn't work, should I use .count ? 
    }
}
```

When I try *.count* it says: "*unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*"

Comment: Hmm. You can try didselectrowatindexpath on both the collectionView and the tableView instead? and update a variable based on the selection, then call your performSegueWithIdentifier and pass the new updated variable to the new ViewController.

Comment: KotaBear233 appears to understand what you want, but I don't. *Why* do you want to use `indexPathForSelectedRow` in `CollectionView`? What are you trying to achieve? What does the second snippet achieve, and why is it not enough?

Answer (score 0):

`collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()` returns multiple IndexPath's because you can select multiple cells. This function returns an array of IndexPaths, e.g [NSIndexPath].

It should work if you'd do something like:

```
let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()

if let lastRowSelected = indexPath?.last?.row {
   dstCtl.levelList = levelListen[lastRowSelected]
}
```

Comment: Says Error:  "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Could you try and change `let dstCtl = segue.destinationViewController as! InLevelViewController`   to:
`guard let dstCtl = segue.destinationViewController as? InLevelViewController else { assertionFailure("destination not of type InLevelViewController") }` Im curious if it will pass this guard.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are using `!` on a variable that is `nil`. You should see at which line the code is stopping when this error is raised, could you copy paste that line?

Comment: line: `let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()`

Comment: And you are sure you got rid of the `!` at that line?

Comment: Yes 100%⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: Haha okey, are you willing to place your code on Git so I can look into it?

Comment: Sure, first time using Git.

Comment: I think the problem is that you haven't linked your `UICollectionView` in your storyboard to the `@IBOutlet collectionView` in your swift file.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, thanks. But it only works with `dstCtl.levelList = levelListen[(indexPath?.count)!` and that doesn't fulfill the same function of the TableView with `indexPath.row`. Any idea?

Comment: See my original answer to get the row

Comment: This doesn't work for me, he gives me the error: `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. It doesn't passed the `if...`. When I try it without the`if`', It says indexPath = 0 values, lastRowSelected = nil.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't know why it's nil. For a quick fix you could always implement this method: `override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { ... }` and open a new VC from there.